# Replace/Consume Istio's Prometheus/Grafana by existing Prometheus-operator

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, grafana

I have multiple K8S clusters that have Prometheus-operator Helm chart installed in monitoring namespace. Each operator consists of Prometheus/Alertmanager/Grafana.
Aside from it I have Istio Helm chart installed in istio-namespace. I want to integrate the Prometheus/Grafana from Istio into my Prometheus-Operator setup and remove them from istio-namespace and the helm release for Istio.
Based on this PR - https://github.com/istio/installer/pull/71
it looks like it's possible, but I can't find exact guidance on how to do it, the end result should be prom-operator prometheus scrapping exactly what it was + what was being scrapped by Istio's Prometheus and then when using the Grafana from prom-operator I should have all mixins + istio dashboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed this guide https://medium.com/@emirmujic/collect-cluster-and-istio-metrics-with-prometheus-operator-42d4499d621a and it worked out for me on Istio 1.2.2:
https://medium.com/@emirmujic/collect-cluster-and-istio-metrics-with-prometheus-operator-42d4499d621a